# How to return list tag from object key and value?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am having an object with data having key and value
In the modal i was planning to show all the data from object in list tag

in `singleproductdetails` i am having object with key and value

```
                     {
                               Object.keys(singleproductdetails).forEach(function eachKey(key) {
                              return (
                                  console.log("hello", key, singleproductdetails[key])
                                 <li className="about-title"><label>{key} </label><span>:</span></li>
                                  <li><p>{singleproductdetails[key]} </p></li>


                                ) 

                              })
                            }
```

Comment: iN CONSOLE i can able to print all key and value

Comment: Unterminated regular expression error i was facing

Comment: What's the problem and what do you want to achieve as a result? What regular expression? Which modal?

Comment: I was trrying to populate all key and value

Comment: In the modal i was trying to populate  all key and values using above code but i am facing error in console i can able to print key and value but why in div if i am keeping showing error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this would work,

`Object.keys(this.props.dataDetail).map(function(detail, id) {
        return <span key={id}>{this.props.dataDetail[detail]}</span>;
    })`

or

`Object.keys(this.props.dataDetail).map(function(detail, id) {
        return (
         <div>
          <span key={id}>{this.props.dataDetail[detail]}</span>
          <span key={id}>{this.props.dataDetail[detail]}</span>
          ... // many items
        </div>
      );
    })`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to return multiple elements in your JSX. Try to wrap your `li` elements in `React.Fragment`

```
Object.keys(singleproductdetails).forEach(function eachKey(key) {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <li className="about-title"><label>{key} </label><span>:</span></li>
        <li><p>{singleproductdetails[key]} </p></li>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `Report`

Comment: @user9883888 can you provide `Report` component sourse? React tells you, that there's a problem there but i can't see it anywhere in code, you provided